# Cannot load google.com

Tags: google-search

I am able to load all other websites, but not `google.com` and `asana.com`. This happens quite often for me. `google.com` gives the following error message.

`This webpage is not available
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Restarting the computer fixes the issue. When they fail to load, the two websites always fail together, and this has happened several times before. Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

P.S. Running Windows 8.1, same behavior seen on Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera. Also, I have Asana extension installed into Chrome, and Asana app added to Google Apps.

Comment: What OS are you using? Can you add the results of  running `dig google.com` when it's working and not working?

Comment: @yoann-h Windows 8.1

Comment: Looks that you have problems with your network settings more specifically with domain name resolving, so the question is more appropriate for the Super User site rather than for the Web Applications site, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try flushing your DNS in Command Prompt: `ipconfig /flushdns`

If it still doesn't load, perhaps try changing your DNS servers, to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.

Comment: +1 This worked. Can you describe what goes wrong and how the flushdns fixes it.

Comment: A DNS cache stores entries on your computer which translate domain names into IP addresses. Sometimes this data may be corrupt or wrong, which was why `google.com` and the other site was not resolved properly. By flushing the DNS cache with `flushdns`, it removes the bad cache stored on your computer and once you try to access `google.com` again, it retrieves new, proper data from the DNS servers, allowing you to access the site.

Comment: Thanks. Could the cache going bad indicate an underlying problem that could be dangerous, like a virus? Should I be worried?

Comment: No problem! It is rarely a result of a virus or something dangerous. It could happen due to a variety of reasons. I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You might try checking your Hosts file.  It's located in "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\".  You can open it with any text editor.  See if you have either of those sites in your Hosts file and delete them if you do.  It would be difficult to believe your DNS server would have some selective issue with just those websites.

Comment: This answer does not explain why it works after a restart

Comment: Well...I was going to get to that if the OP confirmed those entries in his Host file.  If they were there, then some process must have put them there.  But there was no point of going there if that were not the case.  One step at a time.

Comment: @Ramhound Restarting renews the DHCP lease (if you are using DHCP)

Answer (score -2):

You also might try a check for malware.  Some malware blocks sites that might be useful to gather information on disinfecting your machine.

Comment: Malware wouldn't explain why it works after a restart

Comment: @Ramhound If it's something that isn't properly infected--it only runs when he does some particular act, not at startup.